# Javascript Fetch API not loading in Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, fetch-api, firefox-addon-webextensions

Javascript Fetch API not loading in Firefox Extension. I am quiet new here, but how do I solve the problem or what alternatives do I have to get a file from the server in Browser Extensions?

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Fetch a file to change this text.</p>
<script>


fetch ('http://localhost/test/test.txt')
.then(x => x.text())
.then(y => document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1",

  "description": "test",  

  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
     "tabs",
     "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  
  "browser_action": {
   
    "default_title": "test",
    "default_popup": "popup/test.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a separate js file, not an inline script.

Comment: Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. In Firefox it's [slightly more complicated](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/debugging/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved the problem.